# bufferedWriter writes more than it is feeded

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I am trying to read some data and write it to the database and I have a code as follow :

```
try {
    // Assume default encoding.
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);

    // Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

    // Note that write() does not automatically
    // append a newline character.
    bufferedWriter.write("@relation dummy");
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    bufferedWriter.write("@attribute unexpectedness {0, 1}");
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    bufferedWriter.write("@data");
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    for (String[] row : instances) {
        if (counter > 450) {
            bufferedWriter.write(row[0]+", "+row[1]+", "+row[2]+", "+row[3]+", "+row[4]+", "+row[5]+", "+row[6]+", "+row[7]+", "+row[8]);
            //  System.out.println(row[0]+", "+row[1]+", "+row[2]+", "+row[3]+", "+row[4]+", ttt "+row[5]+", "+row[6]+", "+row[7]);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            testRows.add(row);
        }
        else {
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }
    bufferedWriter.flush();
    bufferedWriter.close();
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error writing to file '" + fileName + "'");
}
finally {
    System.gc();
}
```

Which works, but the problem is in the instances I have 400 elements but surprisingly the bufferwriter writes around 5000 lines. Can someone explains why this happens?

**UPDATE:**

I checked the output and it seems that the bufferwriter writes each row 8 times to the text file.

Comment: How are you setting the `instances` varible?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, running example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces your problem? We can only guess what might be the problem, since we don't know what you like to write.

Comment: Did you use the debugger to check what each variable contains at each step?

Comment: Hi again and thanks to @BrianKent I understood that my instance gets duplicates and it has nothing to do with budfferstream, actually for a moment I thought probably budderstream writes other stuff but the problem was my instance

Answer (score 0):

You could use PrintWriter(let's call it pw) to write the file like this:

```
pw.println("bla bla");
```

in this way the writer will write each time on a new line.

Comment: Yes but this way I cannot use the buffered feature which improve speed

Comment: But if the program is not computing a lot of information the speed difference is not that big,that's my opinion you schould now that I'm fearly new at java

Comment: But this is a part of kinda huge work and also time complexity is important